# About BDP formula on getting Volatility of stocks from Bloomberg

Tags: volatility, bloomberg

I have tried VOLATILITY_90D to get the VOLATILITY of stocks from Bloomberg in excel. However, I found that I cannot get the VOLATILITY of some Stocks,such as 330 HK, 3800 HK.

Could anyone help me to solve it? Thank you very much

Comment: It sounds like the kind of problem that Bloomberg Support (F1 F1) would be able to address more efficiently.

Comment: as a side note, i would point out that the bbg api is incredibly inconsistent - fields will have data arbitrarily for some tickers and not for others i would not be surprised if you have to use a different field to get the volatility for some tickers. you can get an idea of it by looking at the `FLDS` page and searching for volatility, and then looking at which tickers have values for which volatility flds and which flds are populated, and then compare it to another.

Comment: (Sorry I don't have Bloomberg Anywhere handy to try what the error is) Both of your examples GCL-Poly and Esprit Holdings seem to have many months of historical prices, so if the API won't give you `VOLATILITY_nD`, then you should be able to compute it yourself from raw data, and trust yourself more than Bloomberg.

Answer (score 1):

thank you for your help and I have asked the help desk from Bloomberg and solve it. The problem is I have spelled the volatility wrongly to volativity.

Again, thank you for all your help.